# Why isn't light scattered uniformly in every direction?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection

Light which reflects off a diffuse reflector is scattered preferentially in certain directions, as can be seen in the following image:

https://www.4physics.com/tn3/brdf_measurements_1_html_m3028b15f.gif

Why isn't light scattered uniformly in every direction by a diffuse reflector?

Comment: You didn't like the previous answer to your question so you asked it again?

Comment: There was no answer so I tried to simplify the question this time. Don't really see how it is a "duplicate" because it's a much more specific question.